# Rate of Divergence ...

Tags: calculus, analysis

Suppose $x_{n}\rightarrow \infty$. We know $y_{n}=\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x_{n}]{x_{n}}\rightarrow 1$. If 
$$
\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x_{n}]{x_{n}}= e^{\frac{1}{\ln n}},
$$ what is the rate of divergence of $x_{n}$ to $\infty$, in terms of $n$?

Comment: Since $\exp(1/\ln n) \to 1$, which is a nonzero limit, what you've written doesn't actually provide any more information than saying that $\sqrt[x_n]{x_n} \to 1$. If you want more information, then you're going to need to say more than just that the two expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Did you mean something like $(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}x_{n}]{x_{n}}-1)\sim (e^{\frac{1}{\ln n}}-1)$?

Comment: Okay, maybe the $\sim$ messes up things. I have changed it to $=$. Is it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
$$x/\ln x = \ln n.$$
On the one hand, we have $x > \ln n$, so $\ln x > \ln \ln n$. On the other hand, for any for large $x$, we have $\sqrt{x} < x/\ln x = \ln n$, so
$$\ln x < 2 \ln \ln n.$$
Now returning to $x = \ln n \ln x$, we find
$$\ln \ln n < \ln x = \ln \ln n + \ln \ln x < \ln \ln n + \ln \ln \ln n + \ln 2.$$
This shows that $\ln x \sim \ln \ln n$, hence
$$x = \ln n \ln x \sim \ln n \ln \ln n.$$